# Ngrams words with TFIDF - Phrases detection using R

Tags: r, tf-idf, n-gram, text-classification, word-frequency

```
TrigramTokenizer <-function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, 
                                            Weka_control(min = 1, max = 3))
Text = c( "Ab Hello world","Hello ab",  "ab" )
tt = Corpus(VectorSource(Text))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix( tt, 
                       control = list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf), tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))
inspect(tdm)


Output

<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 7, documents: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 10/11
Sparsity           : 52%
Maximal term length: 14
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

            Docs
Terms            1 2 3
  ab             1 1 1
  ab hello       1 0 0
  ab hello world 1 0 0
  hello          1 1 0
  hello ab       0 1 0
  hello world    1 0 0
  world          1 0 0
```

This gives me the term frequency however, I would like to have the code basis tfidf like below code. Though I used dtm in the first and tdm in the second, imagine both are tdm and TermDocumentMatrix

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(tt, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix( tt, 
                       control = list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf), tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))
```

My question is how to merge both these codes. I have long list of customer verbatim and by using the first code I could only get the output as shown in the first table however, it has lot of junk. was thinking doing it basis tfidf would resolve the issue. Please help me with this. Alternative way of doing this is also welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that the `R` tag is more appropriate here than `phrase`, so I switched them. I hope, you don't mind. There are more chances to find an answer in the `r` tag, I believe.

Comment: I am fine as long as I get the code to fix this @FreeNickname

Comment: Can't you use the same control for `TDM`?

Comment: I updated my comments @Soheil .  Assume both the codes has tdm only.

Comment: `removeSparseTerm(tdm, 0.2)`

Comment: I tried that and it works however, my main goal is get the Ngrams (1 to 3 words) not just basis the term frequency but also weightTfIdf. Meaning, I am trying to find out if  weighting = weightTfIdf can be inserted somewhere between the following code        tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix( tt,  control = list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf), tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))                Please let me know if I am not clear. @TylerRinker

Comment: tried that and it works however, my main goal is get the Ngrams (1 to 3 words) not just basis the term frequency but also weightTfIdf. Meaning, I am trying to find out if weighting = weightTfIdf can be inserted somewhere between the following code tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix( tt, control = list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf), tokenize = TrigramTokenizer)) Please let me know if I am not clear. @Soheil

Comment: what is contained in weigtTfIdf? Without that we cannot reproduce what you want. but I would say you can just extend the control statement with you weighting.

Comment: Regular output gives us only the Term frequency however, I want to make sure I capture the important phrases/words from the statements I have. That is the reason I want it to merge it weigtTfIdf. I am not sure how to extend the code. Could you please help me with the code? @phiver